# Show that a simple graph is a tree if and only if it is connected but the deletion of any of its edges produces a graph that is not connected.

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-mathematics

I can understand why this is true--it seems really obvious--but I don't know how to formally prove this.

Also, is the first part of this question this question asking us to prove that G is a tree if and only if it is connected? I thought that was a given--part of the defiition of a tree.

Comment: Re-wording.  Let $G$ be a simple graph.  Then ($G$ is a tree) if and only if ($G$ is connected but the deletion of any of its edges produces a graph that is not connected).

Comment: What is your definition of a tree?

Answer (score 9):

Tree is a connected simple graph with no cycles. Now, suppose our graph is a tree, then it's connected. We have to show that if we remove any edge, then it is no longer connected. Suppose we remove edge between vertices $v_1$ and $v_2$ and it's still connected. It means that there is a path from $v_1$ to $v_2$ but if we add our removed edge, then we have a cycle. Contradiction. Now, suppose we have a connected graph from which you can't remove any edge if you want it to remain connected. If it has a cycle then you can remove any edge in this cycle and it's still gonna be connected. It means that it's a tree.

Comment: Damn,you posted your answer just as I finished typing mine. Rats.

Comment: @Mathemagician1234 you can still upvote this one...